# Bus Error when running valgrind on Cavium Octeon III processor

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, valgrind, bus-error

I am trying to run valgrind on my Cavium Octeon III processor. I cross-compiled the valgrind package using below configure command -

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/CAVIUMsdk312/OCTEON-SDK/tools/bin/mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-

./configure --target=mips64-octeon-linux-gnu \
          --host=mips64-octeon-linux-gnu \
          --prefix=/home/prateeka/packages/valgrind-3.19.0/install \
          CFLAGS=-static \
          CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc \
          CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp \
          CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ \
          LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld \
          AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
```

I also created a small application with deliberate memory leak to test the valgrind. On running the application with valgrind, I am getting Bus error.

Command line log:

```
-bash-4.3# export VALGRIND_LIB=/etc/valgrind-bins/libexec/valgrind  
    -bash-4.3# ./bin/valgrind ./mem-leak  
    ==20887== Memcheck, a memory error detector  
    ==20887== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.  
    ==20887== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info  
    ==20887== Command: ./mem-leak  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887== Invalid read of size 8  
    ==20887==    at 0x40BEEE4: __ctype_init (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x40AFC8C: _init (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x40129D8: call_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x4012BC8: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x400328C: _dl_start_user (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==  Address 0xffffffffffff9000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887== Process terminating with default action of signal 10 (SIGBUS)  
    ==20887==    at 0x40BEEE4: __ctype_init (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x40AFC8C: _init (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x40129D8: call_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x4012BC8: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==    by 0x400328C: _dl_start_user (in /lib64/ld-2.16.so)  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887== HEAP SUMMARY:  
    ==20887==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
    ==20887==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible  
    ==20887==  
    ==20887== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s  
    ==20887== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)  
    Bus error
```

I didn't find any illegal virtual address access error in *dmesg* kernel message buffer.

Please suggest how to debug.